# Get Browser Version From Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have written a Firefox extension and am currently in the process of updating it for Firefox 4 and adding some new features.

Firefox 4 has a great new notification display that I'd quite like to use and have found plenty of documentation on how to use it. However, for anything less than 4 I have created my own notification window with specific styles.

My question is: how can I detect whether I'm using Firefox 4 or not in the javascript for my extension. Or, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you're referring to PopupNotifications.jsm then you can just look for the window.PopupNotifications variable and if it exists then you can use it otherwise you can use your own notification window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`nsIXULAppInfo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsIXULAppInfo):

```
var appInfo = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULAppInfo);
// appInfo.version contains the version
```

You can compare versions with [`nsIVersionComparator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIVersionComparator).

Maybe there is a better way, but this definitely works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following links will give you some idea how to do it.

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/822435-how-can-i-get-firefox-version

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: Sorry, I was more looking for something in the Firefox Components services rather than general browser sniffing.